# Network devices unable to start, can't uninstall

Tags: windows-xp, cisco-vpn

Installed a Cisco VPN client on an XP machine, and it totally horked my network cards,  Now the drivers can't startup and throw a code 39 and it added a bunch of "miniport" drivers that also report code 39 (can't start).  Tried uninstalling the drivers, tried doing a netsh int ip reset, tried removing the miniports with devcon, all without success.  Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling any software related to the VPN client and network cards (application, driver, etc), then uninstall any network devices in Device Manager (miniport drivers, network cards, etc) then reboot and let Windows redetect and reinstall the drivers for the network cards.

Answer (score 0):

This is what System Restore is for. Roll it back and try again.

Comment: It's disabled, so I have no snapshot to use